# Configure Javascript in android for showing marker in geoserver

Tags: javascript, android, maps, geoserver

I am able to show Geoserver map using webview (In android) and want to show marker on geoserver map in my android application.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Hope to hear from you soon.

Regards,

Parmanand Soni

Comment: Are you using what kind of map? I have developed an application based Nokia Map with webview and Javascript in android. You can see detail here: https://code.google.com/p/wifi-map-with-nokia-here-api/

Comment: Thank you for helpful response I am using custom map of Geoserver...also tell me how to run javascript on android..

Comment: I don't know about Geoserver... But you can see the source code about how to run javascript: https://code.google.com/p/wifi-map-with-nokia-here-api/source/browse/src/com/buptcoder/wifimap/AllAPMapActivity.java